# Power supply for prototyping with Raspberry PI and motor

Tags: power-supply

I'm going to be working on controlling a motor from the RPI board. The motor needs 12V. I'm thinking of buying a single power supply, to supply both the RPI and the motor with during prototyping. For example, I'm considering this Mean Well 12v supply: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/14099, since it has 2 x 12v DC outputs.

- Can I use this to supply both at the same time?
- Can I use a UBEC to turn the 12v to 5v for the RPI?
- Generally, is this type of power supply a good choice for supplying an RPI plus something else when prototyping?

Thanks.

Comment: Not Pi specific.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Do you know of another forum better suited for this question?

Comment: The key piece I see missing from this is the details about how much power (Amps) the power supply can provide, and how the wiring will be connected to the Pi.  Hence the comment from joan about the question not being Pi-Specific.  Simply getting the Pi to run is the least of this project.  Perhaps https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ could help better.

Comment: What's a UBEC?? Also, check out this question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings/34746#34746